# iCloud backup vs. your own

Tags: icloud, backup, time-machine

I had a mini crisis today after deleting some files by mistake.

I have excellent Time Machine Backup to a local file server and have a history going back for a long time, and fine grained.

However, the files that were deleted were on iCloud/Documents (where so many of my files are.) I assumed this was a redundant backup.

I believe I figured out that files on iCloud are not backed up in a useful way by a local backup. Only their "stubs".

Can someone confirm this for me? This seems like a major loophole or gap.

Comment: Could you edit one or two specific locations you have a suspicion there is a gap in local backups? It’s pretty easy to answer objectively if you have some details to share other than a vague worry that “things” are not usefully backed up.

Comment: I also recall noticing that sometimes "files on iCloud are not backed up in a useful way by a local backup".  Sorry I can't be more helpful ATM.